# accessing django admin using angular frontend

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I want to access django admin using angular frontend. I am not sure if its even possible.

I am using angular as my frontend (angular ver:8.0) and django as my backend.
I have also added admin in my urls.py file as given below

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.debug import default_urlconf

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
urlpatterns = [ 
url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
re_path(r'^superadmin/', admin.site.urls),
re_path(r'^$', default_urlconf),]
```

but when open http://localhost:4203/superadmin/ it doesnt open django admin panel. (http://localhost:4203/ is my local angular server)

How can I achieve this? Is it even possible to use django admin panel with angular frontend?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

the possible solution might be you need to write a new django admin with created a backend services with django REST Framework and then the angular frontend will consume that APIs. But it will require a significant amount of time of coding since you will be rewrite all of the templates in that already provided in Django admin (not to mention that you also need to consider about the security aspect, write unittest, integration and so on)

Hence, its possible that you just keep using the built-in django admin so you can use it quickly since the django admin management itself already has CRUD access to make it easier for you when accessing the models

Comment: yes I also want to use django admin interface only, but how will i access it using angular frontend?

Comment: you can't access it using Angular unless you already create a backend service first to override the django admin functionality, and then Angular will consume your API so that you can access it with Angular as client-side

Comment: so do I have to make component for it in frontend as I cant be able to use django admin interface? Is there no way I can use django admin interface with angular frontend?

Comment: yes, you need to make a component in angular. I think there's a way, either you can use any ready-made CMS or override the django admin directly (but i dont know if its possible to override with Angular). Please refer to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)